# Set the year in a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

How would I go about changing only the year in a datetime object?

I need to call a number of dates from excel, and if the dates I call are before todays date, set the year to 2099.

e.g. date that is called: 15/11/2010 needs to be set to 15/11/2099

Is this doable? or would it be best to change the whole date?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You just need to create a new `DateTime` since `DateTime` is an immutable struct:

```
DateTime newDt = new DateTime(2099, dt.Month, dt.Day);
```

If you want to handle the leapyear issue(source date is in leapyear but target year not), you could use following extension method:

```
public static DateTime ChangeYear(this DateTime dt, int newYear)
{
    return dt.AddYears(newYear - dt.Year);
}
```

This will retain even the `Ticks` and the [`Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx), so it's better than using the `DateTime` constructor. It will return `02/28/2099`  if the orginal DateTime was `02/29/2016`(leap year).

You can use it for example in this way:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016, 2, 29);
DateTime newDt = dt.ChangeYear(2099);
```

Comment: There's a problem with `29 Feb` (e.g. `dt == 29 Feb 2016`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: true, but OP will get a meaningful exception then. What would you do otherwise to "fix" it?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I already pointed this problem, but you can't say that `29 Feb 2016` should be translated to `1 Mar 2099`. What to do with `1 Mar 2016`? It's just an error case

Comment: Cheers for that, I'll have a go.

In regards to 29 Feb it shouldn't matter too much in our system (it only cares about the structure, not what's in it) but would a good shout be to run another check on the day and month and set it to the 28th?

Although, the error would occur in visual wouldn't it, not the end user system..

Comment: @JoshuaCameron-Mackintosh another option for you can be using *leap* year instead of 2099. Then you can be sure that any date will be translated without problems.

Comment: @JoshuaCameron-Mackintosh: i have edited my answer to provide an extension method that handles the leapyear issue

Comment: brilliant. That did the job mate.

Comment: Your code is losing sub-ms precision, and it's resetting `Kind` to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  It should retain both.  Also, you could just check `DateTime.IsLeapYear` instead of relying on control flow by exception.

Comment: @MattJohnson: i don't understand how `DateTime.IsLeapYear` helps, but i've edited my answer to show a completely different and much simpler approach which also retains ticks and the `Kind` :)

Comment: I like this approach better anyway. :)

Answer (score 9):

`DateTime` is immutable type. You cannot change year or any other part of it. You should create new `DateTime` instance with new year. There is no other option.

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now;
var date2 = new DateTime(2099, date1.Month, date1.Day);
```

---

Though you can write an extension if you need to do it often:

```
public static DateTime JumpToYear(this DateTime date, int year)
{
    // you can also provide Hour, Minute, Second and Millisecond
    return new DateTime(year, date.Month, date.Day);
}
```

Usage:

```
var date2 = date1.JumpToYear(2099);
```

Note: February 29 date can become invalid when you change year.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above, this is my extension method to do not get mad with 29th February:

```
public static DateTime ChangeYear(this DateTime dt, int newYear)
{
    if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(newYear) && dt.Month == 2 && dt.Day > 28)
    {
        dt = dt.ChangeDay(28);
    }
    return dt.AddYears(newYear - dt.Year);
}
```

*I know I know, it does not "only change year as the OP wants" but this is my best approach so far ^^*

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the year directly but you can add and subtract from it.
The formula below will set the date to whatever year you set newYear to.

```
date = date.AddYears(newYear - date.Year);
```